# Find files with Android Device Monitor from Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, filesystems, visual-studio-emulator

I have created files with my app and I want to access the files with the Android Device Monitor. This is the path I used

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, 
                               Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments, "somefilename.txt")
```

As result I get the following path, when running on *Visual Studio Emulator for Android*:

`/storage/emulated/0/Documents`

If I start the ADM and look with *File Explorer* I can't find such folder. Because I'm on simulator I should be able to access the files I think. I only have the following similar (empty) folders:

```
storage/emulated/legacy
storage/sdcard0
```

Also under `data/data/appName/` or `data/media/0` there are no files at all. Am I using the wrong path? I don't want to use the real device, because you have to detach and re-attach the cable everytime to see if the files changed ...

If I try to use `adb shell ls /storage/emulated/0/` I get

> No such file or directory

Emulator is running Android 5.0 and the app is compiled with Android 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that I [found the right path](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=42879291&postcount=4) to the symbolic link:

> /mnt/shell/emulated/0/Documents